# How do I create a JavaScript variable from an array of strings without using eval()

Tags: javascript

I know there are a ton of questions about `eval()` alternatives, but I don't think I've come across anything like what I'm trying to do. I apologize if I've come across an answer and just didn't realize it.

Instead of creating a bunch of variables like this

```js
let layerHomes = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
let layerBusinesses = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
let layerParks = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
```

How would I do it like this, but without `eval()`?

```js
array = ['Homes', 'Businesses', 'Parks'];

array.forEach((name) => {
    let layer = `$layer{name} = L.layerGroup().addTo(map)`;
    let polylines = `$layer{name}Polylines = L.layerGroup().addTo(map)`;
    eval(layer);
    eval(polylines);
});
```

I've tried using `Function()`...

```js
collections.forEach((array) => {
    new Function(array, `let layer${array} = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);`);
    new Function(array, `let layer${array}Polylines = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);`);
});
```

...but I'm receiving an error: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: layerHomesPolylines`

Which is weird, because `layerHomes` doesn't throw an error, but `layerHomesPolylines` does?

How do I accomplish this without eval?

Comment: But you have considered `const layer = { homes: L.layerGroup().addTo(map), businesses: L.layerGroup().addTo(map), parks: L.layerGroup().addTo(map) }, layerPolylines = {}; [ "homes", "businesses", "parks" ].forEach((name) => { layer[name] = L.layerGroup().addTo(map); layerPolylines[name] = L.layerGroup().addTo(map); });`, since you _know_ about “a ton of questions about `eval` alternatives”, right? Have you read [“Variable” variables in JavaScript](/q/5187530/4642212)?

Comment: Consider where your time is going. Is time spent trying to figure out this solution better than manually adding the variables?

Comment: One of the problems with doing this is that even if you find a great way of creating such variables, how are you going to *use* them? Every expression involving the variables will pose exactly the same problem, unless you know the names of the variables that will be created. And if you know the names, then you don't have to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign them as properties to `this`, as it by default refers to the current `Window` object.
This is also what you're seemingly doing with your `array` variable, it's added as a property to `window` since you're not using const/let/var.

When nesting into other scopes, however, you have to refer to them through the `window` object directly; which could defeat the purpose of this altogether... and as such, you should instead create an object that is tasked to hold these properties, see second example.

```js
array = ['Homes', 'Businesses', 'Parks'];

array.forEach((name) => {
    this[`layer${name}`] = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
    this[`layer${name}Polylines`] = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
});
```

E.g. this results in `Homes layer Parks poylines`

```js
const layers = {};

const array = ['Homes', 'Businesses', 'Parks'];

array.forEach((name) => {
    layers[`${name}`] = `${name} layer`;
    layers[`${name}Polylines`] = `${name} poylines`;
});

console.log(layers["Homes"], layers["ParksPolylines"]);
```

Comment: Please prefer `globalThis` over `this`, if anything. Just `this` won’t work in modules. Even then, polluting the global object is not a good idea, so definitely go with the `const layers` approach.